# Why is it giving me the error, "the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'", and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, json, urllib

I was following a tutorial about how to use JSON objects (link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5dU2aGHTZg). When they ran the code, they got no errors, but I did. Is it something to do with different Python versions or something?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

def printResults(data):
    theJSON = json.loads(data)
    print (theJSON)

def main():
    urlData ="http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.geojson"

    webUrl = urlopen(urlData)
    print(webUrl.getcode())
    if (webUrl.getcode()==200):
        data = webUrl.read()
        printResults(data)
    else:
        print ("You failed")

main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`HTTPResponse` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#httpresponse-objects) returned from [`urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) reads `bytes` data (raw binary data), not `str` data (textual data), while the `json` module works with `str`. You need to know (or inspect the headers to determine) the encoding used for the data received, and `decode` it appropriately before using `json.loads`.

Assuming it's UTF-8 (most websites are), you can just change:

```
data = webUrl.read()
```

to:

```
data = webUrl.read().decode('utf-8')
```

and it should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks so much! This fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think they were using a different version of the urllib

Try with urllib3 and do the import like this:

```
from urllib import urlopen
```

Hope this is the fix to your problem